# What is the difference between two methods of iterating over arrays using forEach in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

What is the difference between the following two ways to iterate over arrays using `forEach` in Javascript?

```
array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));

array1.forEach(function(element) {console.log(element)});
```

Comment: They are equivalent (for the most part) - your first example uses [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: The first one is often used in ES6. https://engineering.carsguide.com.au/es5-vs-es6-syntax-6c8350fa6998

Comment: Look up difference between old standard function closure and new arrow function syntax.